# Does flex sdk requires java jdk to compile a program?

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Does flex sdk requires java jdk to compile a program?

because when i run a mxmlc.exe, it shows me an error:

```
could not find JRE

could not find java 2 runtime environment
```

Comment: why that is not writted in the documentation of flex sdk?

Comment: Yes it does require JRE to be installed. Are you not using Flash Builder IDE?

Comment: why flash builder does not requiring java, and sdk does?

Comment: Flash Builder automatically installs JRE if it is not found

Answer (score 2):

Install 32 bit JRE! 64 bit version make error like yours.
Check JAVA_HOME OS env variable and/or java.home variable in jvm.config (your_flex_dir\sdks\sdk_version\bin)

Answer (score 0):

Yes JRE is required.

> Stand-alone IDE  - Install this version of Flex Builder 2 if you are
>   not currently using Eclipse™ 3.1.2. It includes a customized version
>   of Eclipse, and its own Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
>   It is mentioned here properly [flex install guide](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/2/install.html)

Comment: i've installed jdk latest version, but it still gives me an error that there are no java runtime environment found, javac.exe and java.exe is in the %PATH%, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: yes its working, but the mxmlc command say that he can't found java environment, i am on windows 7

Comment: Try to reinstall your IDE.

Comment: @Hello: "javac.exe and java.exe is in the %PATH%" -> just add the path to the jre folder to %PATH%, not the actual exes